# Listing files in internal storage only shows file "instant-run"

Tags: java, android

I've got one Activity (we'll call SaverActivity) that saves a file to internal storage. I'm fairly sure that this is working correctly. Then I have a Fragment (ListViewFrag) that's a child of another Activity that is supposed to list all files in internal storage. It was working fine earlier today, but I must have changed something since now it only populates the ListView with "instant-run." I'm fairly sure that SaverActivity is working alright because I saved several files with it that I'm sure I have not deleted, but they're not being displayed..

Here's my ListViewFrag:

```
public class ListViewFrag extends Fragment {


public ListViewFrag() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_view_frag, container, false);

    // reference the list view
    ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.templateFilesList);

    // initialize array list
    ArrayList<String> templateList = new ArrayList<String>();


    // get file directory and make a file[] of them
    File myDir = getActivity().getFilesDir();
    File[] templateFiles = myDir.listFiles();

    // if there's anything in there, file the ArrayList with their names
    if(templateFiles != null){
        for(File file : templateFiles){
            templateList.add(file.getName());
        }
    }

    // adapter for ArrayList
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            templateList);

    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);


    return view;
}

}
```

Relevant XML for ListViewFrag:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/templateFilesList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>

</ListView>
```

And just to be sure, here's my SaverActivity's code:

```
    // Here I get the name of the previous activity via intent
    String templateName = getIntent().getExtras().getString("key1");

    // initializing a new 2d array (the object I'm writing to file is that type)
    String[][] doWArray1New = new String[15][15];

    FileOutputStream fout;

    if(ControllerData.getInstance().doWArray1 != null) {
        // Just putting my data (doWArray1 is a 2d array) into my new 2d array
        doWArray1New = ControllerData.getInstance().doWArray1;

        try {
            // adding the "1" is just my naming convention for this file
            fout = openFileOutput(templateName + "1", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
            oos.writeObject(doWArray1New); // write it
            oos.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Appreciate any input! I'm just confused because I thought I hadn't touched the code since early this morning, so I'm not sure what changed.

Comment: check this one : getActivity().getFilesDir(); what you get in this may be your path has been changed

Comment: @Vickyexpert I think the issue is that I should be using Context.getFilesDir() instead of getActivity.getFilesDir(). But when I try that in my Fragment, "getFilesDir()" says that it cannot be referenced from a static context.

Comment: So I figured this issue out, but my overall problem detailed in my original post still remains.